# How to find the sum of a column based on another column and put it into a new dataframe In R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame looking like this.

| Name | Gender | Count | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | M | 12345 | 0.012313 |
| John | M | 12334 | 0.012314 |
| Robert | M | 12300 | 0.0124 |
| Michael | M | 12222 | 0.13 |
| William | M | 12121 | 0.123131 |
| Mary | F | 10002 | 0.123112 |

I was wondering how i can get the sum of the counts of all of the names that start with each letter of the alphabet in the dataframe and create a new dataframe that looks like

```
Name Count
A    22222
B    44444
C    66666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to provide data with dput:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("James", "John", "Robert", "Michael", 
"William", "Mary"), Gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F"), 
    Count = c(12345L, 12334L, 12300L, 12222L, 12121L, 10002L), 
    Probability = c(0.012313, 0.012314, 0.0124, 0.13, 0.123131, 
    0.123112)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Then just use `xtabs`:

```
Letter <- substr(df$Name, 1, 1)    
xtabs(Count~Letter, df)
# Letter
#     J     M     R     W 
# 24679 22224 12300 12121
```

Or if you want it vertically organized as a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(xtabs(Count~Letter, df))
#   Letter  Freq
# 1      J 24679
# 2      M 22224
# 3      R 12300
# 4      W 12121
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the index into numbers and have the letters be in their own separate column?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(initial = str_sub(Name, 1L, 1L)) %>%
  group_by(initial) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

  initial count
1       J 24679
2       M 22224
3       R 12300
4       W 12121
```

**Data**

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Name,    ~Gender,    ~Count,     ~Probability,
  "James",  "M",    12345,  0.012313,
  "John",   "M",    12334,  0.012314,
  "Robert",     "M",    12300,  0.0124,
  "Michael",    "M",    12222,  0.13,
  "William",    "M",    12121,  0.123131,
  "Mary",   "F",    10002,  0.123112
)
```

Comment: How would I convert the resulting tibble as a dataFrame?

Comment: why `rowwise`?  this `df %>% group_by(initial = str_sub(Name, 1L, 1L)) %>% summarise(count = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE))` will give same results

Comment: @J.corn `tibble` is a also a data frame. The only difference is it has a nicer outputs and shares some information about the variable type and dimension. However, if you like to have a classic data frame I edited my code for that.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I thought it was necessary since I was carrying out a row-wise operation, but it appears you are right.

Comment: even you don't an extra `mutate` if the variable has just been mutated for `group_by` and you may directly create it inside `group_by` thus saving one redundant line of code

Comment: @AnilGoyal Oh you are right! I didn't notice it in your code in the first place. Yes it's a fabulous idea. I remember I say it first in a presentation by David Robinson.You can see the rest of it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDHSBUN_rVU&t=536s

Answer (score 1):

using baseR `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Count ~ substr(Name, 1, 1), df, sum)

  substr(Name, 1, 1) Count
1                  J 24679
2                  M 22224
3                  R 12300
4                  W 12121
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tapply` in base R :

```
with(df, tapply(Count, substr(Name, 1, 1), sum))
```

Or if we you want output as dataframe.

```
stack(with(df, tapply(Count, substr(Name, 1, 1), sum)))
```